# how to create any array list of **numbers** and not strings?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

how can we create an Array list that accepts only the numbers like **int ,float ,double** but not all data types

Comment: JavaScript dose not have type based system by default, you can use Typescript for this, but at the end it will get converted to the JavaScript.

Comment: You need to control that yourself as JavaScript arrays accept several data types in the same array. For example, create a function that checks the data type on entry (i.e. numbers only) and adds the element if it meets your own conditions.

Comment: `List<Double>` - ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Number> someList = new ArrayList<>();
someList.add(1);
someList.add(5.5);
```

Java has [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface. And `Number` - like it says, accepts numbers only.

Comment: It will not. Please try it yourself. You specify the type in `<>` and it will only take that type.

Comment: it is showing error hen i tried to add 1 in to list.what to do now

Comment: @prakash, check my latest edit. You need to cast it to `(double)`. Unfortunately, java does not cast it implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class NumberTest {

ArrayList<Object> numbersAlone = new ArrayList<Object>();

public ArrayList<Object> numbersList(Object number){

    if(number instanceof Integer) {
        System.out.println("This is an Integer: "+number);
        numbersAlone.add(number);
    }else if(number instanceof Double){
        numbersAlone.add(number);
        System.out.println("This is a Double: "+number);
    }else if(number instanceof Float){
        System.out.println("This is a Float: "+number);
        numbersAlone.add(number);
    }else if(number instanceof Long){
        System.out.println("This is a Long: "+number);
        numbersAlone.add(number);
    }else{
        System.out.println("This is not a number: "+number);
    }

    return numbersAlone;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  NumberTest test = new NumberTest();
  float a = 2.356f;  long b = -200000L;
    ArrayList<Object> c = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int x=0; x<10; x++){
      if(x>0 && x<3){
            c = test.numbersList(3.45);
      }else if(x> 2 && x<5){
            c = test.numbersList(a);
      }else if(x> 5 && x<8){
            c = test.numbersList(b);
      }else if(x>7 && x<=10){
            c = test.numbersList(x);
      }
    }
    System.out.println(c.toString());
}

}
```

So create an ArrayList of Objects and put in your numbers. The reverse is the case to get your numbers back. If you want me to add code on how to retrieve the objects, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged the question as `Java`, there's a nice solution - just declare your List like this:

`List<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<>();`

and upon `numberList.add(x);` calls only those `x` values will be accepted that are representing numbers.